# Rendering Library error in Android project

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use an external library in my Android application. After Android Studio updated I had a problem with the project debugging and a layout configuration with 3rd party library.

There are logs below:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no cache in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at ru.yandex.core.CoreApplication.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at ru.yandex.core.CoreApplication.initOnce(Unknown Source)
    at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapSurfaceView.init(Unknown Source)
    at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapSurfaceView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, this error happens when we load native libraries (.so) in this case your 3rd party library and basically this is the explanation:

> When you load native libraries like .so on Linux or .dll on Windows
> using System.loadLibrary() Java looks for those shared library in both
> PATH environment variable and java.library.path system property, If it
> doesn't find shared library it throws "Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no XXX dll in java.library.path".

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in.html#ixzz3bHkcLC27

#### In Android the problem is mainly generated because that native libraries are not accesible to your program, check permissions and paths are correct!.